# NodeJS - Properly catch errors of async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

I was writing a script to pull data from Google Cloud metrics via API when I accidentally discovered that I don't know how to properly catch errors of asynchronous functions. :O

Here is the example code from google cloud:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const monitoring = require('@google-cloud/monitoring');

// Creates a client
const client = new monitoring.MetricServiceClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment and edit the following lines of code.
 */
const projectId = 'XXXXXXXXX';

async function getMetrics() {

  const request = {
    name: client.projectPath(projectId),
    filter: 'metric.type="cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/cpu/utilization"',
    interval: {
      startTime: {
        // Limit results to the last 20 minutes
        seconds: Date.now() / 1000 - 60 * 1,
      },
      endTime: {
        seconds: Date.now() / 1000,
      },
    },
    // Don't return time series data, instead just return information about
    // the metrics that match the filter
    view: 'HEADERS',
  };

  // Writes time series data
  console.log('start')
  const [timeSeries] = await client.listTimeSeries(request);
  console.log('Found data points for the following instances:');
  timeSeries.forEach(data => {
    console.log(data.metric.labels.instance_name);
  });
}


getMetrics();
```

The function `listTimeSeries` returns a promise. I got an error that I need to be authenticated to perform that action, no problem there.

The issue is that I couldn't catch that error.
I tried surrounding the call with `try {...} catch (err) {...}` block, wasn't caught.
I tried to catch it like this `const [timeSeries] = await client.listTimeSeries(request).catch(console.log);` - No luck there.

I must be missing something because I'm pretty new to nodeJS and no way catching errors from async functions is not supported.

I'm using nodeJS v14.

What am I missing guys?
Thank you in advance!

---

**EDIT**

As requested (by @CherryDT), here is the full error output:

[image: Full Err output + stack]

I hope its not too blurry.

---

**EDIT**

It turns out that the way I've been trying to catch errors is fine.
The issue occurred because of `listTimeSeries` function (from an external library), which threw an error instead of rejecting the promise, which is impossible to catch.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Both of them should do it. Can you show the full error message and stack? Maybe it was thrown asynchronously (which would mean a bug in the library)

Comment: It sounds like maybe there's a problem INSIDE the code of `client.listTimeSeries()` and it isn't properly propagating errors back to the caller.

Comment: agreed with others that it's being thrown weirdly, is do you have access to metric_service_client.js:220? Could give some insight

Comment: Ah, yup, it's probably throwing inside an async function:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch go to "Gotchas when throwing errors" in this case there's no way to catch it i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I refer to "async functions" and "asynchronous functions." In Javascript "async function" means a [function created with the async keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), whereas when I say "asynchronous function" I mean in the traditional sense, any function that runs asynchronously. In Javascript, functions created with the async keyword are actually just promises under the hood.

Your code *would* work if errors thrown from asynchronous functions (inside promises) could be caught. Unfortunately, [they can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). Unless the function is using the `async function` [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), errors in promises must be wrapped with `reject`. See the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#gotchas_when_throwing_errors) for the gotcha we're looking at here:

```
// Throwing an error will call the catch method most of the time
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('Uh-oh!');
});

p1.catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e); // "Uh-oh!"
});

// Errors thrown inside asynchronous functions will act like uncaught errors
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    throw new Error('Uncaught Exception!');
  }, 1000);
});

p2.catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e); // This is never called
});

// Errors thrown after resolve is called will be silenced
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve();
  throw new Error('Silenced Exception!');
});

p3.catch(function(e) {
   console.error(e); // This is never called
});
```

I believe [this is the code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-monitoring/blob/cab3fdb02c41149ae40e3a28987bb7ffeed050ac/src/v3/metric_service_client.ts) in the library that's throwing the error, below. Notice that another error is being properly `reject`ed. All comments are mine.

```
for (const methodName of metricServiceStubMethods) {
  const callPromise = this.metricServiceStub.then(
    stub => (...args: Array<{}>) => {
      if (this._terminated) {
        // This is the right thing to do!
        return Promise.reject('The client has already been closed.');
      }
      const func = stub[methodName];
      return func.apply(stub, args);
    },
    (err: Error | null | undefined) => () => {
      // If this was an async function (as in, using the keyword async,
      // not just literally an asynchronous function), this would work,
      // because the async keyword is just syntactic sugar for creating
      // a promise. But it's not so it can't be caught!
      throw err;
    }
  );
```

I believe, in this case, unfortunately there's no way for you to catch this error.

Comment: Let me see if I get this straight. The reason I can't catch the error, is because it was thrown instead of rejecting the promise?

Comment: Thrown from within a Promise, yes. I believe this to be the case if I've indeed found the same library you're using.

Comment: BTW I think that's a bug with google's code, I'm not sure why they wrote it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
(async function() {
    try {
      await getMetrics();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Error occured:", error);
    }
})();
```

Please note that if you are trying to catch the error in `Promise` you can use `.then(() => { }).catch(err => { })` style, but for `async/await` you will need `try { } catch(err) { }` style to catch the error.

**Edit**

By doing this, it **must catch any errors if the promise become rejected**. If you still cannot catch the error, this means that the library you're using doesn't `reject` the promise properly (`Promise.reject()`), instead it did hard-coded `throw error` inside the promise instead of rejecting one. For this case you can't do anything with error catching.

Comment: I assume your -1 is because I tried both methods and mentioned it in the question

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan By doing this, it **must catch any errors if the promise become rejected**. If you still cannot catch the error, it means that the library you're using doesn't `reject` the promise properly (`Promise.reject()`), instead it did hard-coded `throw error` inside the promise instead of rejecting one. For this case you can't do anything with error catching but report problems on Github. To solve you issue, you need to setup service account to authenticate your code with Google Cloud in order for the error to disappear. If this is clear to you, you can remove your -1

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. Sorry Pakpoom, the -1 is not from me.